# preDispatch zend framework 2 not working

Tags: php, zend-framework2

i am having problems in understanding preDispatch below is my code

```
 public function preDispatch(\Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent $e)
    {

        $application    = $e->getApplication();
        $serviceManager = $application->getServiceManager();
        $controller = $e->getTarget();
        $route = $controller->getEvent()->getRouteMatch();
        $hit_controller = $route->getParam('__CONTROLLER__');
        if(strcmp($hit_controller,"Dashboard")==0){
            $authService = $serviceManager->get('Admin\Authentication\Service');
            if (!$authService->hasIdentity()) {
                $pluginManager  = $serviceManager->get('Zend\Mvc\Controller\PluginManager');
                $redirectPlugin = $pluginManager->get('redirect');
                return $redirectPlugin->toRoute('Admin',array('controller'=>'Admin','action'=>'index'));
            }
        }
        return;
    }
```

Below are my routes defined in module.config.php

```
return array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'Dashboard' => array(
              'type' => 'Segment',
              'options' => array(
                  'route' => '/Dashboard[/:action][/:id]',
                  'defaults' => array(
                      '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Admin\Controller',
                        'controller'    => 'Dashboard',
                        'action'        => 'index',
                  ),

              ),

            ),
            'Admin' => array(
                'type'    => 'Segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/Admin[/:action][/:id]',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Admin\Controller',
                        'controller'    => 'Admin',
                        'action'        => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Admin\Controller\Admin' => 'Admin\Controller\AdminController',
            'Admin\Controller\Dashboard' => 'Admin\Controller\DashboardController'
        ),
    ),
    'view_manager' => array(  ),
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
);
```

If i  type in the url

```
public/Admin works fine
 public/Dashboard works fine
 public/Dashboard/edit works fine
 public/Dashboard/edit/11  fails
```

and display the contents of edit/11 . I do not understand why the preDispatch doesn't run on Dashboard/edit/11  ?

Can some one please throw light and guide in the right direction. Any suggestions/  comments/ hlep  are highly regarded. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the brackets in your Dashboard route as follows:

```
'route' => '/Dashboard[/:action[/:id]]',
```